# Firebase push notifications with Ionic3 works on iOS but not on Android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

this and my code to use the native ionic push, in ios is running normally, when i boot the `` this.push.init(options); it asks permission for the user and it works normally, but in android it just does not happen nothing, do not enter into these methods

```
  this.push.hasPermission().then((res: any) => {

  if (res.isEnabled) {
    alert('have permission');

    const options: PushOptions = {
         android: {},
         ios: {
             alert: 'true',
             badge: true,
             sound: 'false'
         },
         windows: {},
         browser: {
             pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
         }
      };

      const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
        alert(notification.message);
      });

      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

      pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));

  } else {
    alert('don`t have permission');
  }

});
```

--

```
 <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="32673134" />
    </plugin>
    <platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Onsignal Push notification. It's very easy.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs